# ExactTarget Enterprise PHP/API How do I select the Enterprise Unit ID

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, php

We have used the PHP code to do Trigger Send Definition with the Standard edition for the past 2 years now, and work very well.

Now we are moving to the Entreprise edition and I was told by ET support that code remain the same, but I only need to include the entreprise ID and the child unit.

I downloaded the PHP API Starter Kit from the link they provided, but I was unable to find the method or function nor any example or documentation on how this should work.

If anyone could point me in the right direction, that would be appreciated.

Thank you.
-Richard

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend taking a look at the sample [SOAP envelopes](http://help.exacttarget.com/Global/Documentation/APIStarterKits/SOAPv3.zip) (direct .zip link) that ET/SFMC provides. Here's a sample SOAP envelope for a firing a Triggered Send configured in a specific business unit.

The `111111` is the business unit ID or MID.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:a="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing">
   <s:Header>
      <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">Create</a:Action>
      <a:MessageID>urn:uuid:b4e94361-3546-45cb-bf01-d6980fd46e0e</a:MessageID>
      <a:ReplyTo>
         <a:Address>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</a:Address>
      </a:ReplyTo>
   </s:Header>
   <s:Body xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <CreateRequest xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
         <Objects xmlns:q1="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI" xsi:type="q1:TriggeredSend">
            <q1:Client>
               <q1:ID>1111111</q1:ID>
            </q1:Client>
            <q1:PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
            <q1:ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
            <q1:TriggeredSendDefinition>
               <q1:PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
               <q1:ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
               <q1:CustomerKey>TRIGGERED-SEND-DEFINITION-EXTERNAL-KEY</q1:CustomerKey>
            </q1:TriggeredSendDefinition>
            <q1:Subscribers>
               <q1:PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
               <q1:ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
               <q1:Owner>
                  <q1:Client>
                     <q1:ID>1111111</q1:ID>
                  </q1:Client>
               </q1:Owner>
               <q1:EmailAddress>email@example.com</q1:EmailAddress>
               <q1:Attributes>
                  <q1:Name>firstname</q1:Name>
                  <q1:Value>firstname</q1:Value>
               </q1:Attributes>
               <q1:Attributes>
                  <q1:Name>lastname</q1:Name>
                  <q1:Value>lastname</q1:Value>
               </q1:Attributes>
               <q1:SubscriberKey>email@example.com</q1:SubscriberKey>
            </q1:Subscribers>
         </Objects>
      </CreateRequest>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```